# mysql multiple-row INSERT syntax where one placeholder is actually a constant

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I am inserting about 3000 records into a mysql table utilizing the [mysql multiple-row INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html). For the sake of an short example this table has only two columns. The actual table(s) of course have more columns where there is an meaningful index ...

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES 
("constant", 1), 
("constant", 2),
("constant", 3);
```

As you may notice **COLUMN A** is always the same value.

Which leads me to the actual question : Is there a way to define **COLUMN A** as a constant within the sql insert statement like described in the following *pseudo code* :

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table (A="constant", B) VALUES 
(1), 
(2),
(3);
```

**Prepared statements ...**

Now this is a little more specific. Some actual perl code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'lalalala' );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( q|INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES ("constant",?)| );

foreach my $increment (1 .. 100000){

  $sth->execute( $increment );
}

...
```

Think this is what i am looking for ? Nope, unfortunately not. As mentioned before i am talkin to mysql over TCP/IP. What the above code actually does is executing this

```
INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES ("constant", 1);
INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES ("constant", 2);
etc ...
```

Every single one of them in a single sql query. Now let alone the query time lets assume 5ms roundtrip time as network overhead. Thats **five seonds** alone in the above example. Now ... i have written a function which solves this mess and creates something a compact query like you see right on top in this question. Now just imagine a concated string as one query with a million inserts. Well it works. Like a charm. However, saving around 50 percent of the traffic by omitting VALUE A as it is actually a constant value which never changes would be even better.

> **Post Scriptum**
>
> If you wonder *why* i ask this and what all this is about ? It comes down to one thing : concating
>   a string that is beeing sent (over the network in my case) to mysql
>   which is then beeing split apart to do something with it when half of
>   the information is redundant ... not efficent imho. IF there is
>   another way - fine. If not i do it like i used to ... with a grain of
>   "does not feel right to me" feeling

Comment: No, but you could define a default value in the table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon thx for commenting. however the value is only the same within the context of one bulk insert

Comment: You could create temp table without constant column. Then you can exexute follow query : insert into your_table select 'A',* from temp_table  . I hope you undertand me . Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Insert the changing columns first and fire another update command for the fixed values.

Comment: @PSK Interessting thought, however this would not work in a case where there is already data in the table "WHERE A=constant" which would change this records too. Not really looking for a edgecase scenario atempt but rather some "feature" in the sql language i dont know off. But i assume there is no such feature ...

Comment: An option: `mysql> SET @\`constant\` := 'constant'; mysql> INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES (@\`constant\`, 1), (@\`constant\`, 2), (@\`constant\`, 3);`.

Comment: @wchiquito I dont see any benefit here over the usual way of bulk insterting. See Post Scriptum for what the goal is ...

Comment: @stewe Can you use prepared statements and use the prepared statement to send several `INSERT INTO` statements with one different value, since the first value is already "hard coded" into the query?

Comment: @Progman see my updates question ...

Answer (score 1):

> mysql> INSERT INTO table (A="constant", B) VALUES

No, there is no such syntax in MySQL. Here's the syntax reference page for INSERT in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

If you want to use multi-row INSERT, you must give an expression for each column in the tuple for every row. The expression can be the same constant on each row, as in your original example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES 
  ("constant", 1), 
  ("constant", 2),
  ("constant", 3);
```

Or it can be a session variable (as @wchiquito commented above).

```
mysql> SET @c = 'constant';
mysql> INSERT INTO table (A, B) VALUES 
  (@c, 1), 
  (@c, 2),
  (@c, 3);
```

Or you can load the values into a temp table and then copy them to the final table (commented by Mauricio Javier Biott above):

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (B INT);
mysql> INSERT INTO temptable (A, B) VALUES 
  (1), 
  (2),
  (3);
mysql> INSERT INTO table (A, B) 
  SELECT 'constant', B FROM temptable;
```

Here's another solution. Assuming `data.txt` contains only the fields you need to have a distinct value per row, you could use [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), and set the invariant column in a final SET clause.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt' 
  INTO TABLE mytable (B) 
  SET A = 'constant';
```

---

You made another statement in your question:

> ...assume 5ms roundtrip time as network overhead.

I think that's an improbable assumption. I just measured the network latency of my app in my datacenter, and it's 36 to 50 times smaller than what you are suggesting.

```
64 bytes from (10.4.12.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from (10.4.12.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
64 bytes from (10.4.12.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from (10.4.12.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
...
```

That's about a tenth of one millisecond per round-trip, not 5ms.

The network latency of executing a prepared statement 3000 times would be at most 414 milliseconds, not 3000 * 5ms = 15 seconds. If the network latency makes your task have unacceptable overhead, you need to improve your network.

Finally, you might like to see the benchmarks I did for my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast) I compare single-row INSERT vs. multi-row INSERT vs. LOAD DATA.

Comment: You are right regarding the round-trip time. However that does not change the fact that it is unnecessary overhead let alone the fact that this is not an actual problem as i have mentioned that i have a function that prepares a single insert statement.

> INTO TABLE mytable (B) SET A = 'constant'; would not work as mentioned before as this would presuppose that the table does not hold any other data. Thank you for your input anyway

Comment: It sounds like you are concerned with the length of your SQL statement. Keep in mind **network latency** and **network transfer rate** are not necessarily related. The latency will not be affected by the length of the query string, but the transfer time will be. You can reduce the length and therefore the transfer time by using a session variable as wchiquito suggested. The LOAD DATA solution I showed is even more compact. But I predict the transfer time will not be a significant bottleneck; the time to execute the INSERT is greater.

Comment: I do admit that shortening the statement by using a session variable helps and i have inlucded this into my wrapper function which was mentioned before. however everything boils down to one thing : "I am talkin about general efficency" Yes you are right when saying "etwork latency and network transfer rate are not necessarily related" but that is cause todays network links messured in either Mega or Giga by todays standards. I think that noone is understand the nature of my question ... which i somehow understsand. I like to use the smallest hammer for the job ...

Comment: Maybe the question should be "is there something better/shorter then multirow insert statement" and then there is a simple answer : "No". I was just curios if there is someone out there with a more elegant sollution to my "problem" which actually is not a real problem but a tendency to make things as fast and slim as prossible.

Comment: The `LOAD DATA INFILE` solution would be more efficient. You would minimize the data to transfer, you only list the constant value once, and it would insert faster too.

Comment: You can also enabled compression on the MySQL protocol. See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql reference to the connect option `mysql_compression=1`.

Comment: Note with DBI you also need to enable the `mysql_local_infile=1` option when you connect to allow LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to work. It's disabled by default.